# File server with incremental patches

Tags: caching, server, filesystems

I'm deploying my build remotely to a file server and clients are downloading it. My build is mostly a loose collection of binary files with some text files. In total the build is around 1 GiB.

However, most of the time I'm making small changes to the executable or small binary data changes so the delta between builds is small.

I'd like to be able to push a build and anyone that downloads the build only downloads the delta. If a new user downloads it for the first time they would get the full build and not the delta. It would also be nice for users to pick a build from the past and grab that build.

I was thinking something like git would work because it has all the requirements that I listed but git requires users to download the entire history of the repository.

I could write something like this myself that has delta patching and compression but I imagined someone has written this before. Does anyone have any recommendations that meet my requirements?

Comment: have you tried `rsync`?

Comment: Business practice has shown, that it's not trivial to maintain patches for all combinations of old and new versions, especially when many files are involved. So most companies, besides the largest ones, release monolithic updates rather than patches.